# Running dev container exec bash not responding

Tags: docker, elixir

I have following Dockerfile:

```
FROM elixir:1.4.5
COPY . /
RUN mix compile
CMD echo "Application started" &&  elixir --name $MY_POD_NAMESPACE@$MY_POD_IP --no-halt --cookie $ERLANG_COOKIE -S mix run
```

It starts and runs well, but when I try either `attatch` or `exec XXX bash` it does not respond at all.

Comment: How exactly do you try to attach in the first place?

Comment: either `docker attach containerid` or `docker exec containerId bash`

Comment: Have you accessed the logs via `docker logs containerId `?

Comment: Yeah, it does work normally

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both the commands are different as such

`docker attach containerid` gets your to main process which was running and if it doesn't output anything further then you will not see anything. You should rather use `docker logs containerid` to see the output of your code

`docker exec containerId bash` means you want to get to a bash process inside the container. This command would execute and end immediately as you have not specified the interactive and the tty flags. Update it to use it as below

```
docker exec -it containerId bash
```

And you should be able to get a bash. If it still doesn't work then use `docker stats containerId` to see what kind of CPU and memory usage your container has

Answer (score 2):

If `docker exec -it container-id bash` doesn't work then try `docker exec -it container-id sh`

Sometimes bash command doesn't work.